# Load Page Only if User Logged in

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'd like to load different pages on a button click on the condition that the user is already logged in (or not). I've tried the below code however I'm getting the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: is_user_logged_in is not defined"

My current code is:

```
if(is_user_logged_in()) 
        {
          localStorage.setItem('mood-board', JSON.stringify(selectedOptions));
          window.location.href = "https://manilva.co/click-to-reveal/";
        } 

        else 
        {
          localStorage.setItem('mood-board', JSON.stringify(selectedOptions));
          window.location.href = "https://manilva.co/register/";
        }
```

Comment: where you have defined `is_user_logged_in`

Comment: If I understand the WordPress documentation correctly, it's defined in pluggable.php or perhaps I've misunderstood this entirely?

Comment: `is_user_logged_in` is a `php` function not `js` function. If you want to do it like that I am writing answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The function `is_user_logged_in` is actually a wordpress internal function and written in `PHP`. So it can not be used in `JS` directly so here is the workaround for this.
So the code should be the following:

```
<?php if(is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
    <script>
        localStorage.setItem('mood-board', JSON.stringify(selectedOptions));
        window.location.href = "https://manilva.co/click-to-reveal/";
    </script>
<?php } else  { ?>
    <script>
        localStorage.setItem('mood-board', JSON.stringify(selectedOptions));
        window.location.href = "https://manilva.co/register/";
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: this is the answer

Comment: Thanks! To double check my understanding, if I have a button and I have this to execute when the button is clicked, I would execute the above PHP inside a javascript function?

Comment: Yes you can so that or you can create a api to check where user is logged in or not and perform action based upon that